# Aurelia and UIkit scrollyspy

Tags: uikit, aurelia, getuikit

I'm trying to use UIkit scrollspy together with aurelia but can't get it to work.  I downloaded skeleton-navigation and installed uikit with jspm. Inside `app.js` I have:

```
import 'uikit';
import 'uikit/css/uikit.css!';
```

UIkit css elements work fine but scrollspy doesn't work. I have something like this inside my html:

```
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-scrollspy-init-inview uk-scrollspy-inview uk-animation-fade" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'uk-animation-fade', repeat: true, delay:1000}"> .... </div>
```

Comment: I think this happen because the dom of aurelia templates is rendered after uikit is loaded. Much like a ajax request, the same happen in jquery, if you put some code in the onready function, the dom will load before the aurelia template, and the function will execute first without any element from the template. The lifecycle method 'activate' from aurelia class can be used but, is a boilerplate, I'm searching for ways to acomodate that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I find a simple way.

Just add *data-uk-observe* attribute in one static container. I put that in the body tag of my **index.html**, because in a aurelia app is the only static thing :-)

That way UIKit will observe for dom changes and when the templates are rendered it will recursively search for new components

I'm not sure of the performance issues, but so far so good.

Example:

```
<body aurelia-app="main" data-uk-observe>
```